# Background process in Django

Tags: python, django

I am a freshman in Django and I have a problem with understanding of implementation background processes. For example, I have:

model.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    math_grade = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    phys_grade = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    avg_grade = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('name', 'math_grade ','phys_grade', 'avg_grade')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

How to implement the next thing: Automatically check (periodically) if math_grade and phys_grade are saved into the DB for this Person, and then automatically f.e. save avg_grade as (a+b)/2

Comment: You could achieve this using a model function in your model class. Or you could do it in your `views.py`. It's better practise to do it in your models though.

Comment: Could you give me an example using my example model?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to run your code periodically for it. you need to just update the `avg_grade` when you have both the number. so just calculate the `avg_grade` when you have both number through a request(else how ll you update the marks.)
Following code should help you to process further.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class UpdateAvgGrade(View):
    def post(self, request):
       data = request.data
       math_marks = data.get('math_marks')
       phy_marks = data.get('phy_marks')
       name_of_person = data.get('name') # as your Person model don't have a User. So using Name to fetch exact user.

       person = Person.objects.get(name=name_of_person)

       if person.math_marks == None:
          # if there are no math_marks present then save math_marks to math_marks from request.
          person.math_marks = math_marks
          person.save()

      if person.phy_marks == None:
         # same thing as math_marks for phy_marks.
         person.phy_marks = phy_marks
         person.save()

      math_marks = person.math_marks # updading this in case you get only value from request and other is present already in DB.
      phy_marks = person.phy_marks

      # now calculate the average grade.
       if person.avg_grade == None:

          # check if you are getting both math and phy marks from request.
          # is yes then you can find the average grade.
          if math_marks and phy_marks:
             avg_grade = (math_marks + phy_marks) // 2 # becase it is int field.
         else:
            return HttpResponse({
               'msg': 'Please provide both math and phy marks.'
            })
      else:
         return HttpResponse({
            'msg': 'avg_grade already present and not udpated.'
         })
```